# Can Someone explain what does this mean in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
   var attr = $($this).attr('checked');
```

I know the dollar sign is for jquery selector but when using $this in the  $() what does this combination mean ?
I need the manning of $($this)  ?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Read: https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified

Answer (score 1):

$(this) is focused on your toggle event

example:

```
<div id="idDiv">
    <div id="idSubdiv">text</div>
</div>

$("#idDiv").click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

from the example $(this).html() will show text

because $(this) in the click function focused on $("#idDiv")